# My Nikon D3100 isn't recognized by Windows 7

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, windows

I can transfer photos fine on my mac, but when I connect it on Windows 7 it appears as an unrecognized device under Windows' device manager (with the little exclamation mark).

Googling didn't return any results, I seem to be the only one on earth facing this issue :P.
I installed View NX 2 from Nikon's website, but didn't install it from the bundled CD (my CD player being dead..).

Any input would be of great help !

Thanks !

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is but my advice is that you should not care. A card-reader is less than $10, runs much faster and does not use the camera's batteries. I have not connect a camera to a computer for years! I currently own 5 different ones, including  [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Transcend-Flash-Memory-Reader-TS-RDP5K/dp/B001NS828K/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1351206503&sr=8-4&keywords=usb+sd+card+reader) which also reads MicroSD cards from my Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer has a SD card reader, you can use it to download your photos.  I've never used my D3000's USB to computer since my computers have SD readers.

I second Itai's comment.  If your PC doesn't read SD cards, obtaining a reader is the easier option.

If you still want to persist with using the camera to PC via USB, and go through "pain" (that I am too lazy to do myself with my D3000), please read on...

NB: I would prefer the SD card reader option as I'd prefer to be taking pictures instead of playing with Windows 7 and its Device Manager.

I had a look at the [Windows Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win7/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=win7&Locale=en-us&TextSearch=D3100&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14) and it reports that the D3100 is compatible for use with Windows 7.

These statements and questions may come across silly and redundant.

Did you connect the camera before installing the correct drivers?  If so, leave the camera disconnected, uninstall the Nikon drivers, and installing the Nikon drivers, and connect the camera.

If you're certain the above doesn't apply, I would try the following:

- remove all USB devices (except keyboard and mouse) from the computer,
- reboot it,
- login, and
- connect *only* the camera and see if Windows 7 is able to correctly recognise the device and *hopefully* download the drivers.

If it doesn't, explore Device Manager, or consult a friend who is very savvy with Windows 7 and using Device Manager or who is patient enough to diagnose drivers.

Comment: For anyone coming along later, rebooting the *camera* can make a difference as well. That means removing and replacing the battery; "off" is really a low-power standby mode on most cameras.

Comment: A card reader should work, but this has its downside too.  When traveling, it's nice to only need your camera, laptop, and a USB cable.  Extra external thingies are just invitation to forget to bring a critical missing part, lose something, etc.  For me at least, it would be worth a little effort to make the direct connection work.  If a simple re-installation of the driver didn't fix things, I would call Nikon support.  You have a right to get what you paid for.

Answer (score 0):

The firmware checks battery level and if it is too low to download all the images in the camera it won't talk to the computer..  Charge your battery and try it again. Should work fine.